Right justified typing in Vim?
I was re-writing some documentation recently and found myself wanting to write from right to left in Vim; but I didn't want to make all the text that way, using for instance set rightleft.
What I'm looking for is more like right justified typing.
Recorded stuff
   Started 1984-08-01T12:77:00
   Current            25:03:00
   Total                   :00
                             ^Place cursor here and type going right to left?


Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further?

Is the solution proposed working for you? Did you already had the time to test it? How can we help you further?

Is the solution solving your problem? Did I miss understood the demand? Should I delete the answer?

This is actually a case where I would prefer to do it in a few simple steps rather than introducing some heavyweight new functionality.
If it's just a few characters I wanted to add, I'd probably ...

insert whatever I wanted to write, e.g. i12:34<Esc>
align the line with :right 30

For a longer line or one with lots of whitespace, I'd add another step:

go back and type over whitespace, e.g. 0RTotal including foo<Esc>


Here is the solution that I would propose:
function! SetRight2Left(yes, col)
  if a:col > 0
    let g:right2left = a:col
  endif
  augroup Right2Left
    autocmd!
    if a:yes
      autocmd InsertCharPre * call Right2LeftInsert()
      autocmd KeyInputPre * call Right2LeftKey()
      autocmd InsertLeave * call SetRight2Left(0, -1)
    endif
  augroup END
endfunction

function! Right2LeftInsert()
  call feedkeys("\<left>\<esc>m'" . g:right2left . "|x\<C-o>:call SetRight2Left(1, -1)\<CR>a")
  if g:right2left > 1
    let g:right2left = g:right2left - 1
  endif
endfunction

function! Right2LeftKey()
  if mode() == 'i' && v:char == "\<Bs>"
    let g:right2left = g:right2left + 1
    call feedkeys("\<esc>m'" . g:right2left . "|i \<esc>\<C-o>\<right>:call SetRight2Left(1, -1)\<CR>a")
  endif
  if mode() == 'i' && v:char == "\<Del>"
    echom "delete"
    let g:right2left = g:right2left + 1
    call feedkeys("\<esc>m'" . g:right2left . "|i \<esc>\<C-o>\<right>:call SetRight2Left(1, -1)\<CR>a")
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> <leader>I col('.')==1 ? "i" : ":call SetRight2Left(1, col('.')-1)<CR>i"
nnoremap <leader>A :call SetRight2Left(1, col('.'))<CR>a

Where <leader>I and <leader>A switch insert mode left to right.
Remark: When escaping from Insert mode the mode is automatically reverted to right to left.
It works by hijacking the InsertCharPre event by feeding some keys to be executed after the insertion in order to correct the alignment (deleting the character that was preceding the insertion point when the mode has been turned on).

This probably makes undo all kinds of weird, doesn’t it?

@D.BenKnoble, the undo seems to work fine :-)

@D.BenKnoble actually ot is no surprise since the code does nothing in the callback but just prepare some keys to be processed after the insertion that are handled normally by the engine (no weired adaptation of the internal Vim model)

Ah, I assumed feeding escapes plus short insertions would make undo only process one char at a time instead of the usual “insert to escape” chunk.
